# iPad keeps charging and uncharging

Tags: ios, ipad

My iPad Air 2 keeps charging and Uncharging. I don’t think it’s a charger problem since I plugged into my iPhone SE and there’s no problem. When I plugged into my iPad, it keeps switching between charging and not charging rapidly.

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2YPN.jpg

Similar to this situation: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6300997

Comment: Please add an answer or tick the "answered" on whether this ended up being the cable or the adapter or the iPad. My "guess" is the adapter can't provide enough current which is why it cycles rapidly when the cable isn't jostled,  but it could be any one of the three causing this.

Answer (score 1):

iPad Air 2 and iPhone SE have different power adapter (head charger unit). iPad Air 2 needs 10W adapter, while iPhone SE needs 5W adapter.

In my experience, I can use 10W adapter for charging my iPhone 6 (which using same adapter with iPhone SE and some users said it will boost the speed). But iPad Air 2 can not be charged with 5W adapter, because it will need more power.

If you have used the correct adapter, make sure there is no problem with the USB cable and your iPad USB port. Because sometime, dust and dirt can disrupt the charging process.

Check this page to identify your adapter: https://www.apple.com/power-adapters/

Comment: This matches my experience. It could be a bad cable or one bad pin, but it's more likely the iPad ***asks*** for more current / wattage than the power adapter can provide and it overheats / trips a protection in the adapter. The iPhone doesn't ask for as much power, so it doesn't push the adapter as hard. I'd test your cable and adapter with another iPad before thinking the charger isn't the cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the video, and the fact that your iPhone charges fine off of the same cable, it looks like there could be debris in the iPad's Lightning port that's preventing the cable from seating fully.

When the cable is plugged into the iPad, see if you can wiggle it slightly from left to right (and if doing so causes it to charge – or not charge – continually, instead of flipping back and forth). If the port is clear, the cable should fit snugly and *not* wiggle.

I've had this happen with both the Lightning port and the headphone jack on various devices. You can use something like a toothpick or a paperclip to try to [clean the debris out of the port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/what-can-be-done-when-the-headphones-wont-stay-seated-in-an-iphone) and that will probably do the trick (just be careful to not damage anything). If you don't want to try this yourself, you can also take it to the Apple Store and they'll do it for you, using (presumably) more specialized tools.

Comment: Yes indeed. I've seen cables where one side of lightning was corroded. That combined with lint in the iOS end meant it would only charge reliably when the corroded pin was down and not up. Looking for lint / corrosion and physical connection issues is needed here. I would bet it's the adapter and not the pins, but between both answers here - there will be a solution.